# How to count the same output?

Tags: python, random

in the following script, I'm trying to count each match, for example, I want to count all 3 matches (how many threes in the output) if you run this script it will give you 100 matches.

```
import random

from collections import Counter
mycoupon = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 7]
for _ in range(100):
    r = random.sample(range(1, 10), 6)
    draws = set(r)
    
    cc = Counter(mycoupon)
    dc = Counter(r)
    common = cc.keys() & dc.keys()
    counts = 0
    for cel in common:
        counts += min(cc[cel], dc[cel])

    #print("My coupon: ", mycoupon)
    #print("Draw: ", draws)
    print("Matches: ", counts)
```

I'm trying to count the "counts" output here

```
counts += min(cc[cel], dc[cel])
```

How is it possible?

Comment: In your code, I got `Matches: 2`. I verified this by comparing the outputs of `sorted(cc.keys())` and `sorted(dc.keys))`

Comment: @etch_45 The thing is, I'm trying to print out the count for example how many twos I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to record the results of each draw:

```
import random

from collections import Counter
mycoupon = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 7]
result = {x:0 for x in range(1, 7)}
for _ in range(100):
    r = random.sample(range(1, 10), 6)
    draws = set(r)
    
    cc = Counter(mycoupon)
    dc = Counter(r)
    common = cc.keys() & dc.keys()
    counts = 0
    for cel in common:
        counts += min(cc[cel], dc[cel])

    #print("My coupon: ", mycoupon)
    #print("Draw: ", draws)
    #print("Matches: ", counts)
    result[counts]+=1
print(result)
```

To only count 3:

```
import random

from collections import Counter
mycoupon = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 7]
result = {x:0 for x in range(3, 4)}
for _ in range(100):
    r = random.sample(range(1, 10), 6)
    draws = set(r)
    
    cc = Counter(mycoupon)
    dc = Counter(r)
    common = cc.keys() & dc.keys()
    counts = 0
    for cel in common:
        counts += min(cc[cel], dc[cel])

    #print("My coupon: ", mycoupon)
    #print("Draw: ", draws)
    #print("Matches: ", counts)
    if counts == 3:
        result[counts]+=1
print(result)
```

Comment: @Z Li Thank you it works perfectly, but what if I want to count only 3 not a range of numbers.. instead of range(1, 7) for example I made it range(3, 4) but it gave me an error. What do you reckon?

Comment: as in threes one line, fours one line, etc... Seperated.

Comment: make `results = 0` and `if counts == 3: result +=1`. Make it `range(3,4)` also works but you need to add an if statement below otherwise `result[counts]` will access other numbers as well and throw an error.

Comment: @Z Li I tried the "results = 0" and "if" approach but the script doesn't seem to work properly because it constantly gives me a 0 and the "range(3, 4)" approach brought confusion to the script!

Comment: Thank you so much! definitely a lifesaver!